# what is regular expression for matching single line with multi match?

Tags: perl, json

```
$str = "Data = [ {"name": "test","Address": "UK" "currency": "£" },{"name": "test2","Address": "US" "currency": "$" },{"name": "test","Address": "eur" "currency": "E" }
```

I want to display all address

its not multi line string . It all a single string

Please help on this

Thanks , 
TREE J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
while ($str =~ /\"Address\":\S+\"(.*?)\"/g) {
      print "Address = $1\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your string is JSON! [Treat it as such](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON)!

**edit**: I'm an idiot and can't tell when a question is tagged as perl instead of PHP :-) Link ammended.

Comment: Correction, bar the `Data = ` at the beginning. Where did you get the data from?

Answer (score 2):

You do it by using the right tool for the job.  In this case you fix the corrupt JSON with a regex and then use [`JSON`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/JSON/lib/JSON.pm) to get the data:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my $input  = <DATA>;
my ($json) = $input =~ /DATA = (.*)/;
my $data   = decode_json $json;

for my $record (@$data) {
    print "$record->{name} has address $record->{Address}\n";
}

__DATA__
DATA = [ {"name": "test",  "Address": "UK", "currency": "£" }, {"name": "test2", "Address": "US", "currency": "$" }, {"name": "test",  "Address": "eur", "currency": "E" } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
my $str = q(Data = [ {"name": "test","Address": "UK" "currency": "£" },{"name": "test2","Address": "US" "currency": "$" },{"name": "test","Address": "eur" "currency": "E" });
my @addresses = $str =~ /"Address":\s*"([^"]*)"/g;
print "@addresses\n";
```

HTH,

Paul

(PS: post real code, not pseudo code...)